# Corp Bond vs cds

Tags: credit

Assume I need to hedge some credit risk. I can buy a bond or cds for it. I see the second option is almost free while the first cost as much as face. Why would people use bonds at all for hedging then?

Comment: What kind of credit risk is a bond hedging?

Comment: Hypothetical,  perhaps better ask why one would use bonds vs cds for hedging at all?

Comment: I feel this is apples to oranges.

Comment: " see the second option is almost free" No, this isn't how CDS trade anymore. See https://www.cdfa.net/cdfa/cdfaweb.nsf/ord/c262660031945ca488257936006983fd/$file/cds_big_bang.pdf . If the quoted CDS spread exceeds the standard running spread, then the protection buyer pays an upfront fee.

Comment: "hedge some credit risk" which one? The P&L upon jumps to default, or the P&L if a credit spread moves and affects marks to market?

Comment: @dimitri vulis: the latter, if the spread of the issuer deteriorates, I need to be hedged. I can use any instrument for hedging in this case that has credit exposure to the issuer. So why do I choose one vs the other? If I do cds I don't need any money for it(at most upfront fee)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are looking to BUY a bond, can I assume your existing position that your are trying to hedge is a SHORT credit risk of an entity?

Assuming you are SHORT the credit risk of an entity, I outline 2 scenarios:

(A)  You are SHORT the bonds

If you are SHORT the bonds, why not just BUY the bonds back?  This would be the most effective neutralization of the credit risk you would have on as it would match the bond on all the fixed income risks as well.

(B)  You are borrowing from the entity

If you are borrowing from the entity, they have credit risk to you.  And therefore you wouldn't need to hedge their credit risk.

So assuming you are really LONG the credit risk, 2 scenarios:

(a)  You are actually LONG the bonds

Again, why not just sell the bonds?  Again, most effective hedge.  If you can't sell the bonds, or like some other feature of the bonds you own (such as the options exposures of a convertible bond), you could SHORT other bonds of the same entity.  You would receive the proceeds from this new SHORT position, which you could then reinvest.  And you would have to pay the costs of borrowing the bond to short.  Additionally, you would probably have to post some initial margin for your short bond position (which has the additional risk of potentially being recalled, at which time you would have to relocate the bond.)

(b)  You have loaned the entity and are unable to get out of the contract.

Again, shorting some of their debt would hedge the credit risk.

In using CDS, you would be buying protection on the entity.  In this case you would be paying premium to the seller of protection.  The seller of protection has credit risk to you and may require an up-front payment from you (as per the contract terms of standardized CDS--as a result of credit risk to the protection buyer after "big bang").  This may cost you more than the initial margin you would have to post on your short bond position.

The CDS (as a standardized contract) is a less effective hedge in that it probably has more basis risk to the position you are trying to hedge.  You would have to manage the other risk over the term of the hedge.  A SHORT bond position may be more effective hedge or not, depending on the mismatch between the hedge and your long exposure, which would also need to be managed.  Also, as mentioned above, the short bond position is subject to recall (a good prime broker would be able to help with this.)

Comment: It is just a hypothetical case. Basically when I read CDS is unfunded it seems as a cheaper option for whatever one wants to do. Given the fact that both bonds and cds can be used for hedging I wonder why one would prefer bonds over cds then?

Comment: So your question is really why would I buy a bond vs selling protection via CDS?  Not necessarily a hedge. Some of this is addressed in my response above.  Some additional points: an unfunded position is leveraged and has more risk; CDS is a derivative exposure and you will have counterparty credit risk in addition to the credit risk of the reference entity.  Obviously, you will be able to invest the cash that would otherwise be paid for the funded position so that is a benefit.  CDS can be physical or cash settled upon a default. These all have pros and cons.  This is a long topic.

Comment: I see, so even though it doesn't require funds I will take an additional risk with cds vs bond.

Comment: Additionally, if the OP long a credit in the form of bond or loan or some debt being marked to market, and for some reason don't want to just unwind this position, then they can also sell a participation or a total return swap on it. Or even a TRS referencing some other bond  may be actually easier than shorting a bond. Shorting illiquid bonds can be hard.